# How to report a difference in means - Demographics

Tags: mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, reporting, demography

First of all sorry for the question, I'm having a hard time with statistics :)

I have conducted a survey for my thesis and am currently analyzing and reporting the results. At the end of my survey, I have asked participants about their attitudes toward different concepts (each measured by a singular likert-type item). Now, I would like to highlight differences between respondents of different gender. I have not formulated hypotheses or anything here, but I think it's still interesting to mention.

One exemplary insight reads: *"On average and compared to women, men reported a more positive attitude toward Artificial intelligence (Mmale = 5.6, SD = 1.423, Mfemale = 4.38, SD = 1.210)."*

**Now my question is: Does this statement provide any additional value or do I need to conduct another test that examines significance, before reporting it (Mann-Whitney U in this case)?**

It seems a bit excessive to me to do it for every question and I am also wondering how to report if there is no significance. Can I just mention it or do I also need some values like here: "A Mann-Whitney U test revealed no statistically significant difference in attitudes between men and women (U = 8025.000, z = -0,431, p = 0.618)."

Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could*, simply mention the differences, but I think you really should carry out a formal statistical test.  While the difference you provided looks like there's a big difference in men compared to women (5.6 vs. 4.38), the standard deviation of your female measurements is about 15% lower than the males.  It's hard to tell by simply reading your assertion that this is a statistically signfiicant and interesting result and not simply a result of your sampling variability.  I think it's prudent that you carry out formal tests to make sure you're not saying something that really isn't true (e.g. men are more likely to report favorable use of AI than women).

If you're concerned about the repetative nature of the results in your prose or in cluttering your writing with the parenthetical results, I'd suggest simply putting together a table of your averages, standard errors, and and $p$-values.

By the way, in your quoted example, you are reporting a standard deviation, but I think you need to be reporting standard errors. Also, why do you only report one signfiicant digit for men (5.6) and two for women (4.38)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! In that case, I will conduct a Mann-Whitney Test for each of my assumptions (and maybe put them together in a table). 

The second digit was `0`so I dropped it, but good point! And also thanks for the remark with the SD/SE - so far I only reported the SD because that's what I saw in other studies - but now that I caught up, it seems like you report the SE when comparing means. Will use that info to replace the SDs :)

Comment: Great.  Yes, I figured that the last digit was a zero, but just wanted to point it out so you could ensure consistency in your reporting (i.e. you should include the zero if you are keeping two digits afte the decimal).  Standard deviation measures how spread out values are in a variable. Standard error measures the accuracy with which a sample distribution represents a population (e.g. the mean).